# How can I include styles in multiple TikZ pictures?

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-styles

Let's consider this simple example of a TikZ picture that defines the node distance and a style called `mynode` within the square brackets:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[
  node distance=2.5em, auto,
  mynode/.style={draw=black, rectangle, minimuim size=2em},
]
\node[mynode] (name) {label};
\end{tikzpicture}
```

When create another TikZ picture within the same LaTeX document, I can copy the content between the square brackets to get the same style.

However, I have to update all figures separately to change the style. How can I define the content between the square brackets in a central place and use it in multiple TikZ figures?

Comment: You can use `\tikzset{<options>}` somewhere in a higher group to apply settings for that group, or you can set them in your preamble for global settings.

Comment: @Max Thanks, that's very helpful. Is there a way to specifically include styles into pictures instead of making the styles available globally?

Comment: Well you could nest styles. An example: `style a/.style={style b/.style={draw,minimum size=2em}}`. Then if you if you call `style a` at the start of your `tikzpicture` like `\begin{tikzpicture}[style a]`, it will make `style b` available for use. But if you don't call `style a`, it is not available.

Comment: You can create say a `header.tex` file containing all styles then `\input` this file in the preamble of your figures if you precompile them as `standalone` document

Comment: Similarly you could globally define `style b`, and let `style a` overwrite it locally. Then if you call `style a` for a certain picture, it uses the overwritten `style b`, and pictures without `style a` use the original `style b`.

Comment: @Max That's exactly what I was looking for. Would you mind writing this out as an answer below so I can accept it?

Comment: @danijar You could ask a new question that is more specific to what you would want to achieve. Something like "How to locally install Tikz styles that can be changed globally?". This would also attract more users so possibly more and better answers. It may seem tedious to ask a new question, but for future reference it is better to have a title that corresponds to what you want.

Comment: @Max Makes sense. Here is the new question: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/448897/61219